# Apple hardware issue. Battery not charging, service recommended

Tags: macbook-pro, battery

Battery not charging. Service recommended.

I bought this MacBook Pro 13 inch retina exactly 5 years ago and it was working perfectly fine until now. But, all of a sudden it stopped working, then I plugged in the power adapter and tried to power it on, it started with a chime but took way longer than usual to boot up. On the home screen, it showed battery not charging, service recommended.

I went to  store, after inspecting the Mac for just a minute they told that the battery needs to be replaced and the fare they mentioned is very high. So, I bought a battery with one year warranty and replaced it myself with the help of ifixit document. Everything is fine and the Mac booted up. Now, in the Mac home screen, same problem again, the battery is not charging even after plugging the power adapter for 12 hours continously. The cycle count of the new battery is 0.

I'm unable to understand what the problem is!! The Mac works perfectly fine with the power adapter plugged in and the magsafe light is amber. As soon as I disconnect the power adapter, the Mac stops working and shuts down.

I ran the  diagnostics and the response codes were PPP003 and PPT006.

I tried different things to identify the problem:-
changed the power adapter, it's still the same.
Cleaned the contacts between power adapter and macbook pro, it's still the same.
Reset SMC, it's still the same.
Reset PRAM, it's still the same.

Please help me out!!!

Answer (score 1):

The response codes from Apple Diagnostics are listed in https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT203747:

- **PPP003**: There may be an issue with the power adapter. Disconnect the MagSafe power adapter from the computer and the power outlet, then reconnect. Run the test again.

  If this code appears a second time, further troubleshooting may be required. Contact Apple or take your computer to an Apple Authorized Service Provider or Apple Retail Store to determine which service and support options are available.
- **PPT006**: The battery requires service. The battery is not functioning normally, though you may not notice a change in its behavior or the amount of charge it holds. You can continue to use your battery before it’s checked without harming your computer.

  Contact Apple or take your computer to an Apple Authorized Service Provider or Apple Retail Store to determine which service and support options are available.

So there still seems to be a problem either with the power adapter or the battery. Without access to the hardware it's impossible to analyze this further so it's probably best to visit the Apple Store again.